# MSFT crawling killing my linksys E3000

Tags: router

I currently run a website with a Linksys E3000 router. Normally, theres about 2000 connections to the linux box, but when microsoft comes around, it makes over 4000 connections, and kills my internet to a snail. Bandwidth is not the issue here, the server only does about 300KB/s down and 80KB/s up, the router simply cannot handle the connections.

Can someone suggest a business router that can handle say 20,000-50,000 concurrent connections or tell me a way to block that annoying microsoft spider! Currently we have a robots.txt (it ignores it and crawls a certain link when people post our link in the social media space). We tried iptables, which does seem to REJECT the connection, but nonetheless, the packet goes from internet -> cable modem -> linksys e3000 -> linux box (reject) and back out.

Thanks everyone. Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: if you're comfortable with nix why not just use an old linux box as the router? or inline transparent firewall in front of the router...

Answer (score 1):

> block that annoying microsoft spider

Is it ignoring [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) or something?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having a problem with an E3000 running very slow.  If I connected to the cable modem directly then everything was fine.  As soon as I connected via the router everything got very slow!  I just did the 30/30/30 reset on the router and it seemed to fix it.  That is hold down the reset button (with it powered on) and then count to 30, then uplug it (keep holding down the rest button) and count to 30, and then plug it back in and count to 30.  Make sure to hold down the reset button throughtout the whole 30/30/30 reset prodecure.

Now you just need to confugure it again because it will boot with all the default settings!  Remember the id/password -> admin/admin.

Comment: Word of caution - I've bricked my router when doing 30/30/30 - it's not fully safe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Asus RT-N16 can handle 300,000 connections. there is a review  here: http://onlinetechadvice.blogspot.com/2010/11/linksys-wireless-routers-review.html

Its a great router in general, 64MB Flash 128MB RAM, Fast CPU. Gigabit Ethernet, DNLA Streaming, 2 USB Port for print server or download files.